# AddRelativeForce doesnt add Relative force

Tags: unity-game-engine

First of all. I am pretty much a blank beginner and was trying to make a little game in unity.
It's a stick that gets `addforced` up and rotated at the same time.
Now the problem is that when I add the `transform.up` force, it is bound to the objects z rotate and not the global
Is there any way around that?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class LaunchCAR : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb2D;
    public float thrust = 10.0f;
    public float torque = 1f;

    private void Start()
    {
      
       transform.position = new Vector3(0.0f, -2.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            rb2D.AddRelativeForce(-(transform.up) * thrust, ForceMode2D.Impulse);

            
           // float turn = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            rb2D.AddTorque(torque, ForceMode2D.Impulse); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`AddRelativeForce` expects object-space (local) coordinates, but you're passing `transform.up` which is in world-space coordinates.

Use either `Vector3.up` or `AddForce` instead.